# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

```
     $(function() {


var retrievedtext1 = localStorage.getItem('t1');
var retrievedtext2 = localStorage.getItem('t2');

      retrievedtext1=JSON.parse(retrievedtext1);
      retrievedtext2=JSON.parse(retrievedtext2);


   document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = retrievedtext1;

   document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = retrievedtext2; 

          var changeq=0;
    var obj= OS.length;

    console.log(obj);
          document.getElementById("element").src =OS[changeq].image ;

    $('#Fairly1').click(function() {

        alert('value = 1'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);

          changeq +=1;

        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ;


        if (changeq>=OS.length){

            window.location.assign("start.html");

        }



});
    $('#between').click(function() {
           alert('value = 2'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);
        changeq +=1;              
        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ; 

});
    $('#Both').click(function() {
            alert('value = 5'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);
        changeq +=1;              
        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ; 

});
    $('#Non').click(function() {
            alert('value = 6'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);
        changeq +=1;              
        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ; 

});
    $('#x').click(function() {
            alert('value = 4'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);
        changeq +=1;              
        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ; 

});
    $('#Fairly2').click(function() {
            alert('value = 3'+"--"+OS[changeq].image);
        changeq +=1;              
        document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ; 

});

         });


   function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined`.

I want it so that after I loop through the JSON object, I redirect to another page and save what user did in one array to send it later to db.

Comment: What is in the variable `OS`?  You should do a `console.log(OS[changeq]);` as it is probably `undefined` and thus your error when you try to reference `OS[changeq].image`.  Really nothing more for us to do here as your data probalby isn't what you think it is so you get an error trying to access something that isn't there.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? What is your question?

Comment: OS is JSON object and i already code work and show the pictures and loop but i wanted after finishing looping to direct the user to another page and i was trying to use if and making comparison with the JSON object array . normally when i was making var obj= OS.length;

    console.log(obj); i was getting the array length and OS[changeq].image give me image source so i can show it

Comment: i was testing on the first button only to see if it gone work or not and what happen that it loops till end and then i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
changeq +=1;
document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ;
```

You are increasing `changeq` first, before accessing `OS[changeq].image`. You are not checking whether `changeq` is still a valid index into the array!

The simplest solution would be to switch the lines. If that is not possible because it changes the desired behavior, move the check in between:

```
changeq +=1;
if (changeq>=OS.length){
    window.location.assign("start.html");
    return;
}
document.getElementById("element").src = OS[changeq].image ;
```

Comment: It works, but i have another problem now that when it start. it start with first  picture[0] in the array    after i click fairly button it show the first picture again and until i click again it change this because i increase changeq after showing the picture

Comment: That's why I suggest an alternative solution at the end. Or of course you could initialize `changeq` with `1` instead of `0`.